# How do I access a virtual attribute from a gem in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, acts-as-taggable-on, rspec3

In my `Dashboard#Index` I have this in my controller:

```
tagged_nodes = Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(current_user.email)
```

This is my spec:

```
it "assigns all the nodes that are tagged with the current_user email to local variable 'tagged_nodes'" do
  get :index
  expect(assigns(:tagged_users)).to eq Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(@user.email)    
end
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:tagged_users)).to eq Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(@user.email)

       expected: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
```

I suspect it is because of the `tagged_with` which is a helper method from the gem [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

Is that what is indeed causing this error? If so, how do I get around that?

If not, what could be causing that error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reproduce this problem *outside* of your tests? If not, I think that's the first logical step.

I'd start by trying to reproduce this issue in the controller itself (ie. in your controller action, sprinkle `puts` statements or insert a `binding.pry` if you have the excellent Pry gem). If `@tagged_users` gets populated properly in the controller action when running the dev site, but doesn't get populated when running a spec with the exact same setup, then consider it an Rspec issue. This boils down to "eliminate as many variables as possible in order to isolate the problem".

Comment: Yep. This works properly in my controller. What is happening is I am adding tests after the fact. So the controller works right now, with that logic, and I am trying to work backwards.

Comment: Ah got it. In that case I'd recommend the `pry` gem. Add it to your gemfile (`test` and `development` groups) then add the line `binding.pry` somewhere within your code (in this case the controller action). When Ruby execution hits that line, it will stop and provide you with an interactive console where you can query variables, make changes and so forth, in order to determine why the variable isn't getting populated as expected.

Comment: Incidentally you're probably aware of TDD/BDD, both of which encourage you to write all specs *before* writing the corresponding implementation; I understand this approach quickly eliminates this sort of issue. Unfortunately I've never gotten the "aha" moment of BDD and found it agonizingly tedious, so I'm frequently in the same boat as you. ;-)

Comment: Yeh I am trying to get to TDD, but the first step is adding tests to existing functionality - which is what I am doing here :)